# Пакетное чтение из БД с помощью Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Я использую `CriteriaBuilder` для вычитывая всех данных из БД.
Когда число записей доходит до 2 млн начинаются торможения.

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory1 = entityManagerFactory.getEntityManagerFactory();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory1.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<BIS_DATA> critQuery = builder.createQuery(BIS_DATA.class);

critQuery.select(critQuery.from(BIS_DATA.class));

Query<BIS_DATA> query = session.createQuery(critQuery);
List<BIS_DATA> results = query.getResultList();
```

мне интересно есть ли аналог в Hibernate из JDBC Statement .setFetchSize(fetchSize);
и как отключить запись данных в кэш при чтении?

Answer (score 1):

по обоим вопросам ответ: да

1. размер JDBC fetchSize задается через `org.hibernate.Query#setFetchSize`: тут нужно или кастануть `Query<BIS_DATA> query` к `org.hibernate.Query` или выполнить `javax.persistence.Query#unwrap` - в JPA API такой возможности, увы, не предусмотрено, а в конкретной реализации - без проблем. Хотя, с другой стороны потенциальный профит от этого не очевиден поскольку в конце концов на выходе оказывается список, а не курсор/стрим (т.е. если БД - `Oracle`, то выигрыша не будет никакого, потому что там и так по умолчанию `fetch size` указан довольно разумный, в случае `PostgreSQL` можно по используемой памяти в каком-то моменте выйграть в 2 раза).
2. чтобы сущности из результата запроса не оседали в персистентном контексте, можно сказать хиберу, что мы не собирается модифицировать полученные данные, т.е.: `org.hibernate.Query#setReadOnly`